# An stronger inequality than in AoPS.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

For $x,y,z >0.$ Prove$:$

$$\sum {\frac {y+z}{x}}+{\frac {1728 {x}^{ 3}{y}^{3}{z}^{3}}{ \left( x+y \right) ^{2} \left( y+z \right) ^{2} \left( z+x \right) ^{2} \left( x+y+z \right) ^{3}}} \geqslant 4\sum {\frac {x}{y+z }}+1$$

I check when $xyz=0$ and $x=y$ and see it's true. So I guess it's true.
So I try to get it in $uvw$ form as follow$:$

$$-26244{u}^{7}{v}^{2}{w}^{3}+19683{u}^{6}{v}^{6}+2916{u}^{6}{w}^{6}+4374{u}^{5}{v}^{4}{w}^{3}-2673{u}^{4}{v}^{2}{w}^{6}+216{u}^{3}{w}^{9}+1728{w}^{12} \geqslant 0$$

Then I don't know how to end proof for it. BW does not help here.

I'm not sure about this inequality. I found it when I prove [this inequality.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2172783p16191292)

Help me please. Thanks for a real lot!

Comment: Did you try BW by $z = 1, \ y = 1+s, \ x = 1 + s + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$ (WLOG, assume $x\ge y \ge z$)?

Comment: @RiverLi I had tried BW by $x=x,y=s+x,z=t+x$ and see BW does not help here. I'll try your.

Comment: Works when $x$ is piecewise: $x=1+s+(1+t)$ and $x=1+s+1/(1+t)$, because Michael Rozenberg mentioned that equality also occurs for $(2,1,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$uvw$ helps!

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v>0$,  and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{9uv^2-3w^3}{w^3}+\frac{1728w^9}{(9uv^2-w^3)^2\cdot27u^3}\geq\frac{4(27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3+9uv^2-3w^3+3w^3)}{9uv^2-w^3}+1$$ or
$$\frac{9uv^2}{w^3}+\frac{64w^9}{u^3(9uv^2-w^3)^2}\geq\frac{4(27u^3-9uv^2+2w^3)}{9uv^2-w^3}$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=64w^{12}+8u^3w^9+108u^6w^6-99u^2v^4w^6-972u^7v^2w^3+162u^5v^4w^3+729u^6v^6.$$
But since by Maclaurin $$u\geq v\geq w,$$ we obtain: $$f'(w^3)=256w^9+24u^3w^6+216u^6w^3-198u^2v^4w^3-972u^7v^2+162u^5v^4<0,$$
which says that $f$ decreases and it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is homogeneous and symmetric, it's enough to assume $y=z=1,$ which gives:
$$(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x^4+10x^3+37x^2+20x+4)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Now we see, why BW does not help: the equality occurs also for $(x,y,z)=(2,1,1).$

Comment: Maybe $uvw$ is a nice solution for this inequality. But how to prove $f'(w^3) < 0?$

Comment: @knvy144444 It's obvious because $u\geq v\geq w$. See please better my post. Just  because $972>162+216+24+256.$